# Wordpress: Responsive Design - iPad view incorrectly

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, woothemes

I'm working on a Online Shop with WooCommerce and the free responsive theme Mystile.
The website looks perfect on the computer and also on 4.7 inch and 5 inch smartphones.
On smartphones another navigation bar shows up to provide better usability.

Only on tablets, for example on the iPad, the site looks incorrect and unadjusted and the mobile navigation doesn't appear too.

Here's the CSS code: http://textuploader.com/x4vq

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Add a media query that targets the tablet resolution size and add a styling to it. Nothing else can be done to fix it...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a beginner could you say me what I exactly have to do? Creating a new CSS, adding something to the current CSS?

Comment: Mystyle already has a layout.css in the css folder of the theme, where media queries are located. Currently it has only `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {}`, you can add your own like `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {}` and such. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) link out.

Comment: Technically, if it already works for mobile resolutions at  `768px` then perhaps if you change that to `979px` it could have the desired effect. You'd be enabling the navigation to turn into the mobile-view at larger screen sizes (ipads) but with the same styles as before.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys! I tried to create a "@media only" section for the 979px width. I used this code "@media only screen and (min-width: 979px) {}" in the brackets I just pasted the content of the "@media only 769px" but on the iPad it doesn't look good.